# Deleting a directory in emacs' dired mode

Tags: linux, emacs

I would like to delete a directory in emacs' dired-mode.  I mark the directory with the "d" key, and then hit "x" to deleted flagged.  I then get the following error:

```
file-error Non-regular file is a directory <name of dir>
```

Is there any way to get emacs to delete the directory and stop its whining?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what emacs version you have, mine gives me this error:
`(file-error Removing directory Directory not empty ...)`
For empty directories, it doesn't complain.

Anyway, in the version I have, there is a variable: `dired-recursive-deletes` that decides if directories can be deleted if they have some content. You should thus customize this variable with:

`M-x customize-variable`

and then when prompter specify:

`dired-recursive-deletes`

You can then choose the behaviour by clicking on the "Value Menu" button and then save it with the button at the top of the buffer.

Comment: In .emacs: `(setq dired-recursive-deletes 'top)`

Comment: And with my version of emacs, with my personnal settings I don't remember tweaking about this, it just asks me if I (really) want to recursively delete the directory, and then proceeds.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is:
a. MARK (m) the directories you want to delete;
b. Position POINT on one of the marked files;
c. Type '!' [dired-do-command], at the prompt "Execute command ..." enter "rm -Rf"
d. Type 'g' to refresh the dired buffer because emacs doesn't know you changed the filesystem.

That last step could usefully be made an option for dired: "Refresh the buffer after shell command."
Maybe it already is one.

BTW, the 'dired-recursive-deletes' gets me a "[no match]"